# Angularjs page refresh broken for only one page in app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the Agularjs refresh returns 404 bug that has been well documented over the past few years, but I'm experiencing this issue on only one page in my app.  I have several pages that all resolve to their pages on refresh except for my user info page.  Here is the routing code I have for it. I have included the route for my dashboard page (which works) as well.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider.
        state("home", {
            url: "/dashboard",
            controller: "dashboardController as vm",
            templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/view.html',
            resolve: {
                user: ['oauth',
                    function (oauth) {
                        return oauth.getOrLoadUser();
                    }]
            }
        }).
        state("updateInfo", {
            url: "/updateInfo",
            controller: "updateInfoController as vm",
            templateUrl: 'app/account/updateInfo.html',
            resolve: {
                user: ['oauth',
                    function (oauth) {
                        return oauth.getOrLoadUser();
                    }]
            }
        }).
```

As you can see I'm setting Html5Mode on for my locationProvider, and the route is identical to my other routes.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
Here is what my routeConfig looks like.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        Dictionary<string, string> handleInHome = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        handleInHome.Add("login", "login/{*catchall}");
        handleInHome.Add("dashboard", "dashboard/{*catchall}");            
        handleInHome.Add("aboutus", "aboutus/{*catchall}");
        handleInHome.Add("requests", "requests/{*catchall}");
        handleInHome.Add("faq", "faq/{*catchall}");      

        foreach (var key in handleInHome.Keys)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: key,
               url: handleInHome[key],
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
           );
        }           


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I tried adding a catch all for the accounts folder, but I didn't make any difference.
handleInHome.Add("account", "account/{*catchall}");

Comment: this is possibly a problem on the backend. Can you show us the code for your backend routing?

Comment: @AJFunk I added my routeConfig.cs file.  Anything else we should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to handle the `/updateInfo` route on the backend to make sure you serve your Angular app for this route.

`handleInHome.Add("updateInfo", "updateInfo/{*catchall}");`

Comment: AH, THANKS!  I thought I had to put the catchall on the folder that UpdateInfo sat in.  That's why I tried handleInHome.Add("account", "account/{*catchall}");  (UpdateInfo sits inside of account).